# Sucking Candy and Chewing Gum in Bathroom

Tags: halacha, food, bathroom

One is not allowed to eat in a restroom. Does this apply to actually putting food into one's mouth or merely having food in one's mouth? If I am chewing gum and want to go to the bathroom, is it necessary to spit out the gum first?

Answer (score 1):

> May one chew gum on a fast day?
>
> The authorities debate the question of
>   whether chewing constitutes “eating”
>   in the Halachic sense. Hacham Ovadia
>   Hedaya (1890-1969), in his work Yaskil
>   Abdi, rules that chewing gum is not
>   considered “eating,” and thus one does
>   not recite a Beracha before he chews
>   gum. Hacham Ovadia Yosef, however, in
>   his work Yabia Omer (vol. 7, Orah Haim
>   33), disagrees, and rules that if one
>   chews gum coated with sugar or other
>   sweetening agent, he must recite the
>   Beracha of She’hakol. By the same
>   token, it would be forbidden to chew
>   sweet chewing gum on a fast day. One
>   may, however, chew a substance that
>   has no flavor, such as wax used by
>   people wearing braces, as this
>   certainly does not constitute
>   “eating.”

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1786

*According to the of the Yaskil Abdi where you do not make a Bracha on chewing gum as it is not considered eating then you would be allowed to chew gum in the bathroom.*

Comment: I think you still have to demonstrate why you think the parameters of what constitutes eating should be the same for making a beracha and going into the bathroom.

Comment: I agree with @IsaacMoses, this answer does not seem very relevant.