# Is the brochah made on gum for the base or the flavoring?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, ikar-tofel

When the brochah shehakol is made on gum, is the brochah being made on the gum base, or the flavoring? (I'm assuming one makes a brochah on gum, but maybe not: see http://torahmusings.com/2010/11/chewing-gum-bracha-or-no-bracha/.)

Comment: Yabia Omer O"C vol. 7. I'd post it if I had access, but I'm sure you're plenty capable of looking it up yourself. Its around the 20's  (simanim-wise), addressed to his son R. Yitzchak.

Comment: Could "_hana'as garon_" be derived from the gum base, which never usually makes it to the throat?

Comment: It might depend on each person but i would think probably not.

Comment: @WAF if "garon" literally meant throat, you could pretty much never be hayav for something because it is a *beriya*-it usually wouldn't be whole by the time it gets to your throat.

Comment: @BaalShemotTovot Very interesting!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6788/1172

Comment: What's the difference which 'thing' I'm making the bracha 'on'?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'd imagine you can have cases with one without the other...

Answer (score 1):

Rav Yishak Yosef writes that you make the Beracha on the flavoring combining with the saliva.

Comment: So you make a bracha on saliva that tastes good?  I'm really confused

Answer (score 1):

It is on the flavouring. According to the famous Birkas Hashem (maamarim 1, quoted by the responsum on the topic - see below), there wouldn't be a need for a Bracha on flavourless gum.

People don't typicaly chew such gum today, choosing only flavoured gums.

http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/kosher-gum.html

> While there are poskim (Birkas Hashem, maamarim 1) that hold that one does not recite a bracha before chewing gum, most follow R’ Ovadia Yosef (Yabia Omer 7 OC:33) and R’ Ephraim Greenblatt (Rivevos Ephraim 6:80:2) and recite shehakol.

Answer (score 0):

The flavoring 
This is based on the psak of the rambam that one who sucks on sugar cane for flavor even though they are not eating anything still makes a shehakol.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you could please provide a reference to the Rambam.

Comment: And the Rambam you are quoting does not say you aren't eating anything.  He just says it isn't a fruit.  He compares it to date honey.